# sikuli setup doesn't start

Tags: java, sikuli

I've downloaded sikulixsetup-1.1.2.jar file, but after opening it some window blinked for a second and then nothing happened. During my next tries even this window isn't blinking.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

My OS is Windows 10, java version - 10.0.1.
Environment variables seem to be set properly:
"where java" command returns this path "C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin\java.exe",
"where javac" command returns this path "C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin\javac.exe"

UPD: Launched jar file from command prompt as administrator, got this error message:
[error] RunTimeINIT: Java version not detected (using 7): 10.0.1+10
java ?7?-64 version 10.0.1+10 vm 10.0.1+10 class 54.0 arch amd64

Comment: Try running the JAR file with `java -jar` from a command prompt and look for any errors in the output. That may give you a clue as to why it's failing. From there, if you can't figure it out, I recommend taking this question to the [Sikuli Launchpad site](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli). You'll get more specialized help there, and probably with better results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolution is as follows - current stable release of SikuliX (1.1.2) can't interprete current Java release (10.0.1) properly, but it's already fixed in Sikuli 1.1.3 (nightly release now).
For more information about it - see corresponding SikuliX's bug report (https://bugs.launchpad.net/sikuli/+bug/1766117).
Thanks @Brian for giving me a great clue about where should I search for it :)